# String cause NullPointerException

Tags: java

This is my code. I just read file that have lines first is number then lines as string their number equal the number in first line.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
 class groupmember
{
int recieving;
int giving;
String name;
groupmember()
{
    recieving=0;
    giving=0;
    //name=null;
}
public void setname (String Title)
{
   this.name = new String(Title);
}
public void setrecieving(int val)
{
    recieving=val;
}
public void setgiving(int val)
{
    giving=val;
}
public String getname()
{
return name;    
}
public int getrecieving()
{
    return recieving;
}
public int getgiving()
{
    return giving;
}
}
class gift1 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        BufferedReader f=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("gift1.in"));
        PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("gift1.out")));
        StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());
        int NP=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());

        int excpectedgived=0,div=0;
        groupmember []groupmember=new groupmember[NP];
        for(int i=0;i<NP;i++)
        {
            st=new StringTokenizer(f.readLine());           
            String name=st.nextToken();

            groupmember[i].setname(name);
        System.out.println(name);   
        }

        out.close();
    }

}
```

The problem arises on this line:

```
groupmember[i].setname(name);
```

It causes `NullPointerException`. I want to know why this happens.

Comment: I can't find `groupmember[i].setname(name)` anywhere, but looks like `groupmember[i]` is `null`.

Comment: I cann't even find `groupmember[i]`

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: sorry edit is done now

Comment: The relevant code is missing, but I think the cause is that after `groupmember []groupmember=new groupmember[NP];` all the array elements are `null`. Thus `groupmember[i].setname(name);` would - unless you have a `groupmember[i] = new groupmember();` in between - try to invoke `setname` on `null`. Also, your class names should start with an upper case letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupmember[i]` is never defined, you need to add

```
groupmember[i] = new groupmember();
```

or something like that at the start of your cycle.

Comment: yes this is problem,thanks

Answer (score 2):

An array of reference type variables is filled with `null` entries after initialization. You need

```
groupmember[i] = new groupmember();
```

before you can do:

```
groupmember[i].setname(name);
```

---

In future, please follow the Java Naming Conventions and have your classes start with an  uppercase letter, like `GroupMember` (even CamelCase).

Answer (score 0):

You have just initialised the array of type `groupmember`, now all the values in the array are null, in order to start using the array, you need to do .

`groupmember[i] = new groupmember();`

Answer (score -1):

Do this: String name = ""; String have default value null if they are not initialized.

Comment: only if they are instance variables.....